# Cannot find reference for "SubmitChanges" 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception

I am writing a web service, using C# and Linq. I am fairly new to this, and using tutorials on line I have been able to do most everything I need. I have web services for a variety of complex operations on my database.

Where I *have* run into a problem is with adding records to my tables. I have followed a number of tutorials, which all seem very simple, but I have a reference that I am clearly missing and cannot find. I am using SQL Server (2008), and have built a WCF Service Library. The start of the code is:

```
public const int RET_OK = 0;
public const int RET_NOT_OK = -1;

public const int RET_TICKET_NO_SERVER = -1;

int retInt;
xxxxEntities3 xxxxDB = new xxxxEntities3();

public int CreateTicket(ref string strServer)
{           
    if ((strServer == null) || (strServer.Length == 0))
    {
        return(RET_TICKET_NO_SERVER);
    }

    ticket tick = new ticket();
    tick.serveTime = DateTime.Now;
    tick.server = strServer;

    xxxxDB.tickets.AddObject(tick); 

    return (0);
}
```

I have made sure to add a reference to the System.Data.Linq assembly, and I have verified that the .edmx file is correct (all of my "reading" web services work great).

The problem is that when I try to insert changes (with something like this):

```
xxxxDB.tickets.SubmitChanges(tick);
```

I get that the SubmitChanges is not found (it asks if I am missing a reference). Am I? I am sure this is very simple, but I must be too tired - I just don't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is `tickets` defined? I don't see it.

Comment: It's just a table in the schema that was brought in by Visual Studio when I included the SQL Server table...

Answer (score 3):

Isn't `SubmitChanged` defined on at the root of the database layer? This is my experience with LinqToSql. For instance, you would manipulate things on a table by table basis, but push changes at once:

```
database.table.InsertOnSubmit(entity);

database.SubmitChanges();
```

Now, it looks like you're using a slightly different LinqToSomething mechanism that I'm not entirely familiar with - but many of the principles are not doubt shared.

As brought to attention by @Henk and @Kirk, there are a couple of things to consider here:

- With EF, the call should apparently be on the context itself, as suggested
- With EF, the call to make is `SaveChanges` as opposed to `SubmitChanges`

Comment: As @Henk implies, the OP appears to be using EF.  Therefore, the method would be named `SaveChanges`.  However, you're also correct that this needs to be invoked on the data context (`database`) rather than the table.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Yeah, definitely not an _on a platter_ answer here, I'll update to express the wisdom, that I lacked, gleaned from yourself and Henk.

Comment: NEVER MIND. I had an issue with the code I tried out to "fix" the issue. That's fixed and it inserted just fine. Thank you SO very much.